# Shelve добавление в один файл разные словари и в разных тематиках

Tags: python, файлы, list, tkinter, данные

Господа, подскажите куда читать?
Ситуация следующая, реализовал сохранение полученной от пользователя информации посредством `Shelve` - но оный генерирует 3 файла на выходе.
Меня больше заботит другой вопрос: у меня 3 категории для пользователя, следовательно он может что-то добавить и формируется список с внесёнными пользователем значениями, который сохраняется в определённый для этой категории файл. Таким образом получается аж 9 файлов хранения. Я хотел бы узнать, можно запихнуть всё в один. Дело в том, что все значения из каждого списка потом распаковываются в `TreeView` и я не знаю, как их вытаскивать по 3 разным категориям из одного файла не перепутав, если все они будут там.
Пример того, как сохраняются данные:

```
bd_games = shelve.open('bd_games')
bd_games[f'{Name.get()}'] = [Name.get(), combobox_Pass.get(), combobox_Platform.get(), combobox_Fan.get()]
bd_games.close()
```

Ключом служит уникальное название которое назначает списку пользователь, затем сохраняются все остальные данные. Таких категорий 3 и каждая сохраняется в свой файл, затем они извлекаются в TreeView для каждой категории:

```
bd_games = shelve.open('bd_games')
for key in bd_games:
    tree_games.insert("", END, values=bd_games[f'{key}'])
```

Возможно ли всё загружать в один файл так, чтобы потом можно было вытащить "правильно" списки для каждой категории. Не могу найти что-то подобное, подскажите где почитать, был бы благодарен...

Comment: Вы можете хранить в `shelve` ведь любые структуры. На верхнем уровне это словарь, но ничто не мешает вам поместить в него ещё словарь и работать дальше с ним. Например: `bd_games['категория 1'] = {f'{Name.get()}': [Name.get(), combobox_Pass.get(), combobox_Platform.get(), combobox_Fan.get()]}`

Comment: Не поверите, сам же пришёл к такой мысли и понял, как глупил - не видя очевидного ответа. Спасибо за отклик! =)